# how to hot reload code while using ritz-nrepl

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am using emacs, clojure-mode, and ritz-nrepl.

I have set up my code to reload on change, while using swank-clojure using the following - [How to Reload files upon save when using swank+leiningen+emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596222/how-to-reload-files-upon-save-when-using-swankleiningenemacs)

How do I adapt it, so that my code is also compiled and reloaded while using ritz-nrepl.

Answer (score 1):

It should be **C-c-M-n** if you're using nREPL, but unless you need something specific in ritz, I would recommend nrepl.el because it replaced swank-clojure project. => https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el

Comment: The debugging functionality is being offered by ritz, but I will also try out nrepl in the meanwhile, thanks.